# Uploading program to an ATJ3315D (Chinese MP3-player chip)

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, microprocessor, mp3

I have an Intenso Music Mover MP3 player laying around, so I decided I want to mod it to play Snake.

I know Assembly basics and I decided that this would be a cool project to do. I am quite new to embedded programming, but I still want to try.

I already figured out the chip and its architecture. It's a Z80-compatible [ATJ3315D](https://datasheetspdf.com/mobile/774999/Actions/ATJ3315/1), manufacturer's homepage [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20110908082732/http://www.actions-semi.com/en/product.aspx?id=31) (as it was in 2011; the current one does not have it on there anymore).

The MP3 player has a micro-USB connector. My main problem now is that I need a way to program the chip with my own firmware.

How are MCUs usually programmed, and how can I reprogram mine (and maybe even read the current firmware)? I would prefer not buying any hardware and not soldering anything.

[image]

The chip right beneath the controller is serial flash ([datasheet](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/555293/WINBOND/25032BVSIG.html)), so it might just be possible to overwrite that with the new firmware.
I was also told here and on Reddit that the chip might also just hold the music. Doesn't it just stream the music data right from the SD card? Anyway, I can probably just solve that question by trying to read what's on there.

Comment: Mcu’s can be programmed in a variety of ways. What you need to know is this particular one is programmed. For all we know the code might be loaded at the factory into one time memory?  Seems info is thin on the ground, so you might be stalled in your endeavours.

Comment: Right, that seems to be a problem. I have these two images of the board: [Image 1](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/993465016416219136/1019164347186024448/IMG_20220913_113328_edit_1756188144598684.jpg), [Image 2](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/993465016416219136/1019175896160161822/IMG_20220913_122040.jpg). The chip seems to have RAM integrated, so I would think (but not hope...) that the compontent next to it is read only memory, essentially killing the project...

Comment: The 8pin chip might be serial flash which can be easily reprogrammed. Search the part number.

Comment: @Kartman My eyes hurt, and I can barely see because I of the flashlight, but I have the part number, and it is indeed serial flash! [Here is a Datasheet](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/555293/WINBOND/25032BVSIG.html). Now, do you maybe have a starting point on how to read and write to it? Thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add all this important information to your question. This is not a forum, and visitors will refrain from reading all comments to collect potential details. -- The data sheet of the serial flash tells you all necessary details to read and write it, it has even a table of contents. :-D But I'm afraid that it is just the onboard memory for music, not the program. -- The data sheet of the MCU mentions a boot and firmware update ROM, but there is not a bit of information how this works. You need to search more, i.e. for a user's or programmer's manual.

Comment: High volume commercial products very likely come with pre-programmed MCUs. And it's highly unlikely that they would pick a MCU running the code from external flash, because that's an expensive (and outdated) design. The external flash is far more likely used for storing sound files, because those will take up way more memory than what the MCU got internally.

Comment: Furthermore the LCD driver might be custom or proprietary so how are you going to write to the display? This project idea overall seems to originate from a lack of electronics knowledge.